# Get and return the ID to execute "edit" action

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

I've a module made using "tabs", each tab call a component in this way:

```
include_component('logotipo', 'index');
```

Now this is the code for the component:

```
class logotipoComponents extends sfComponents {

    public function executeIndex(sfWebRequest $request) {
        $id_empresa = $this->getUser()->getGuardUser()->getSfGuardUserProfile()->getIdempresa();
        $this->sdriving_logotipo = Doctrine_Core::getTable('SdrivingLogotipo')->createQuery('a')->leftJoin('a.SdrivingEmpresa e')->where('e.idempresa = ?', $id_empresa)->execute();
    }

}
```

And  this is the template `_index.php`:

```
<?php if ($sdriving_logotipo->count() > 0): ?>
    <div class="span3">
        <span class="gris">Vista previa</span>
        <?php echo image_tag('/uploads/' . $sdriving_logotipo[0]->getArchivo()); ?>
    </div>
<?php else: ?>
    <div class="alert alert-block">
        <h4><?php echo __('Información!') ?></h4>
        <?php echo __('No se ha subido ningún logotipo aún. Haga clic en el botón "Subir nuevo" para crear uno.') ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

This code works fine, but I need a bit more. What I need to do here is update logotipo uploading a new one and delete the existent from file system and also from database or just editing the existent record and updating values. Now takes a look at this `schema.yml`:

```
SdrivingEmpresa:
  columns:
    idempresa:
      type: integer(4)
      unsigned: true
      primary: true
      autoincrement: true
    idlogotipo:
      type: integer(4)
      unsigned: true
      primary: true
    nombre_empresa:
      type: string(250)
      notnull: true
    ruta_emp:
      type: string(45)
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
  relations:
    SdrivingLogotipo:
      local: idlogotipo
      foreign: idlogotipo
      type: one
    SdrivingEmisor:
      local: idempresa
      foreign: idempresa
      type: many
    SdrivingMaquina:
      local: idempresa
      foreign: idempresa
      type: many
    SdrivingOperador:
      local: idempresa
      foreign: idempresa
      type: many
    SdrivingTurno:
      local: idempresa
      foreign: idempresa
      type: many
    SfGuardUserProfile:
      local: idempresa
      foreign: idempresa
      type: many

SdrivingLogotipo:
  columns:
    idlogotipo:
      type: integer(4)
      unsigned: true
      primary: true
      autoincrement: true
    archivo:
      type: string(250)
  relations:
    SdrivingEmpresa:
      local: idlogotipo
      foreign: idlogotipo
      type: many
```

Taking this if I pick the first option then I need to build a query for get the filename from DB and then delete the file from file system, upload the new file and update `SdrivingEmpresa` table with the new ID for uploaded file. In this case I don't know how to get the ID and where to write the logic for those actions: in `protected function processForm(sfWebRequest $request, sfForm $form) { }`? in 'doSave($con = null){ }' at `SdrivingLogotipoForm.class.php`? Where?

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you use ajax. Create a module called ajax and develop the logic in the actions and templates there.

When you click on each tab to run the ajax form action.

It is my recommendation.

good luck.